# bind variable does not exist

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE TEST3(CREATED_BY_IN IN VARCHAR2,SRC_NAME IN VARCHAR2,TGT_NAME IN VARCHAR2,OUTPUT OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
CHECK_STATUS INTEGER;
SRCSQL VARCHAR(1000);

BEGIN


 SRCSQL:= 'INSERT INTO TBLCNT SELECT '||''''||CREATED_BY_IN||''''||','|| ' COUNT(*),' ||''''||SRC_NAME||''''||' FROM  '||SRC_NAME ;



EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SRCSQL USING CREATED_BY_IN,SRC_NAME;

OUTPUT:=SRCSQL;
END;
```

Iam getting the error stating 'Bind variable does not exist'.
Can anyone please help me with this

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Re-tagged with `plsql` as this is obviously PL/SQL for Oracle

Comment: Good on you for using the USING clause! You definitely want to avoid concatenation whenever you are simply concatenating in a VALUE (as opposed to a chunk of SQL text). That will improve performance (reduce the number of hard parses) and also make your code less vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 3):

You are performing a query with concatenated text and variable, so you can't use execute immediate with binded variables since they are not used in this case.

the right syntaxe is :

```
 SRCSQL:= 'INSERT INTO TBLCNT SELECT :p1, COUNT(*), :p2 FROM :p2';


EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SRCSQL USING CREATED_BY_IN, SRC_NAME, SRC_NAME;
```

See documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use this without the help of bind variables. Hope below snippet helps .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST3(
    CREATED_BY_IN IN VARCHAR2,
    SRC_NAME      IN VARCHAR2,
    TGT_NAME      IN VARCHAR2,
    OUTPUT OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
  CHECK_STATUS INTEGER;
  SRCSQL       VARCHAR(1000);
BEGIN
  SRCSQL:= 'INSERT INTO TBLCNT SELECT '||''''||CREATED_BY_IN||''''||','|| ' COUNT(*),' ||''''||SRC_NAME||''''||' FROM  '||SRC_NAME ;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SRCSQL;
  OUTPUT:=SRCSQL;
END;
```